# Query was empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 4 colums - id, store_name, lat, lng in my table 'stores'. I want to display all results that are in radius in 30 miles. I got this:

```
$lat = '25.7742644';
$lng = '-80.1936558';
$miles = 30;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
           ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) 
           * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
           * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) 
           + sin( radians($lat) ) 
           * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM stores
        HAVING distance < $miles 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0, 20 ");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


    echo $store_name;



    }
```

but when I start the script I get "Query was empty"?

Comment: Your `distance` calcualtion is returning a zero... Seems like this line is the contributing factor `* cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) )` ... otherwise distance results in 8643.135040508392... Isn't it drastically huge compared to the 30 miles radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<?php

$lng = '-80.1936558';
$lat = '25.7742644';
$miles = 30;

$query = "SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( lnggitude ) - 
radians('$lng') ) + 
sin( radians('$lat') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM yourtable HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 20";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row["store_name"] . "<br />";
}

?>
```

[Tutorial link.](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

Comment: Well I dont get any erros I just have empty white page?

Comment: @ZdravkoNikolov that `echo $store_name;` isn't right, you have to use `echo $row["some_name"];`

Comment: That means you have no stores within 30 miles radius isn't it? :)

Comment: @bonCodigo no, it's just that he didn't output the results properly and thus he got an empty page

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, ...")
^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
          ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
```

Get rid of one of those `mysql_query`.

Comment: Warning on line :
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in MY_URL/index.php on line 32

Comment: It means something was wrong with the query and `mysql_query` returned `false` instead of a result resource. This should be caught by `or die(mysql_error())`, but I don't know if you removed that too.

Comment: @zdravko: your query is failing, returning a boolean false, which you've blindly used in the fetch call. add basic error handling: `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to find out why the query failed. **NEVER** assume a query succeeded.

Comment: Now I got thi error:
Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'